# Criminal procedure to dismiss a case

Tags: traffic, new-york-state, rules-of-court, criminal-procedure, motor-vehicle

When one has been summoned to a pre-trial conference in a municipal court over a minor traffic offense, if one wants to request, pro se, from the judge a dismissal of the case, it would seem to be counterproductive and inappropriate to plea bargain first with the prosecutor. In any event, in this situation, may one decline to confer with the prosecutor until after any negative ruling on the request to dismiss the case? How may one do this?

Comment: A pre-trial conference is for scheduling and bringing motions.

Comment: A clerical worker in the court has told me that I must meet first w/the prosecutor. Is she wrong?

Comment: She is wrong. You have no obligation to speak with the prosecutor at any point. But in my experience, doing so is usually a good idea.

Comment: WRT close votes. I would point out that the querent is just asking about a legal procedure for NY state in a general sense, they aren't asking for how to resolve their specific case.